# Getting a part of String Omitting Tags using Jquery

Tags: jquery

From Below code, Please consider <#><#> as some HTML Tags

var s = <#>heading<#> I want to get this text;

I want to manipulate & get "I want to get this text" only.

required result:
alert("s >> " +s);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var output = $('<div>').html(s).contents().last().text().trim();
```

Output:

```
"I want to get this text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1> I want to get this text';

alert($('<span>').html(s).contents().filter(function(){
     return this.nodeType==3;
}).text());
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/23Hf8/1/)</kbd>